# Can every even number be written as $(p-q)/6$ where $p,q$ are primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

For $n$ even, assume

$\large n = \frac{q-p}{6}$

For $a,b \in\mathbb{N}$, primes $p,q$ can be written as

$q = 6a\pm1$

$p = 6b\pm1$

There are $4$ possible cases

***Case 1***

$n =  \frac{(6a-1)-(6b-1)}{6}$, then $n=a-b$

***Case 2***

$n =  \frac{(6a-1)-(6b+1)}{6}$, then $n = a-b-1/3$

***Case 3***

$n =  \frac{(6a+1)-(6b-1)}{6}$, then $n = a-b+1/3$

***Case 4***

$n =  \frac{(6a+1)-(6b+1)}{6}$, then $n=a-b$

For Cases $2$ and $3$, $n$ cannot be even because of $\pm 1/3$.

For Cases $1$ and $4$, both result in $n=a-b$.

Not sure how to proceed from here?

Comment: This question is equivalent to asking whether every multiple of 12 is the gap between two primes; this is an open question.

Comment: @GregMartin "gap" is usually used in the case of consecutive primes. Here the primes are arbitary, but I think the problem is still open.

Comment: It is strongly conjectured that every even prime gap appears (even infinite many often). If this is true, then we can even find consecutive primes $p$ and $q$ for every positive integer $k$ (not just the even ones) such that $q-p=6k$ implying that every positive integer can be written this way.

Comment: Dixon's conjecture also implies that , for every positive integer $k$ , there is a prime $p$ such that $q=p+6k$ is also prime. Hence $k=\frac{q-p}{6}$ , as desired.

Comment: @Peter If $k\leqslant10^8$ is even, then there is a prime $p\leqslant1117$ such that $p+k$ is prime. (Critical case: $p=1117$ is the lowest prime where $p+55076404$ is prime.)

Comment: @RosieF No idea what I programmed. I repeated it , and your summary is correct.